# Fine frequency correction : grouping and finding max amplitude inside a group

Tags: digital-communications, frequency, amplitude, doppler

I work on phase and frequency estimation algorithm. Currently I am working on a derivation and determination of the Doppler shift( dF – frequency step).

For each dF, The following algorithm was applied for group of sample - M (base band):

1. M is filtered by RRC FIR filter
2. Compute amplitude Amp(i), where I is an index of frequency
3. Sum the N adjacent samples up: AmpSum(j)
4. Find a max.

For the maximum value determined in this way(dF), a fine correction is then carried out . This is a weighted averaging in order to determine the mean frequency within the detected bandwidth for different signals CW, random data ...

I have tested with groups of 4,6,7,8,9,10 and decided firstly to check fine correction with a group of 9 samples.

What do you think?

Could you let me know what your thoughts are on such algorithm? Could I use it? what have i to consider ( important for me)?

PS I simulate a low data rate receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP mentions an index of frequency I assume a missing step not shown is an FFT is computed on the M samples, and the algorithm is to determine the maximum frequency.

I would not recommend such an approach to determine Doppler offset and fine frequency tuning except for initial acquisition (course tuning), given the computation involved in the FFT compared to what is alternatively explained below. Also I would expect that the maximum peak of an FFT on any given capture would be quite variable for modulated waveforms.

A favored algorithm is the cross product frequency discriminator which is the imaginary term of the complex conjugate product of adjacent time domain samples of the complex baseband waveform (or can also be applied to correlator outputs etc), where baseband waveform is the modulated waveform with only a residual carrier offset to be determined.  This works as the imaginary term of the complex conjugate cross product is proportional to the phase between two complex phasors. If the two phasors are values separated in time, then the result is a change in phase over a change in time, which is frequency (as $d\phi/dt$). What is beautiful about this approach is that the imaginary term of the complex conjugate of two phasors given as $I_1+jQ_1$ and $I_2 + jQ_2$ is simply $I_1 Q_2 - I_2Q_1$, or $I[n] Q[n-1] - I[n-1]Q[n]$ for each time domain sample $n$ of the complex waveform. Such a result can be averaged for very fine frequency offset correction.

[image: Cross Product Phase Detector]

The imaginary term is the scaled sine of the angle (scaled by the square of the input amplitude), and for small angles $\sin(\phi) \approx \phi$, so can be effectively used in a recovery loop which would drive that angle to zero. It is typical to AGC (automatic gain control) the waveform first so that the signal amplitude is not controlling the loop time constant as it otherwise would.

[image: Phase Detector]

This is often used in a decision directed carrier recovery loop such as shown in the block diagram below specific to a QPSK demodulator:

[image: Decision Directed Phase Detector]

Note that the autocorrelation function is composed of conjugate multiplications of a signal with delayed versions of itself (!), so the imaginary term of the complex autocorrelation result is itself a frequency discriminator (cool!), as demonstrated in the plot below. There are many more computations than necessary in an autocorrelation (which can also be efficiently computed using FFT's as $\text{fft}(x)\text{fft}^*(x)$ where $\text{fft}^*(x)$ is the complex conjugate of the fft result) but wanted to include this in case similar processing was being done for other reasons such as spread-spectrum receivers or pilot detection, or if this can otherwise facilitate acquisition. For ongoing carrier tracking, I would recommend the simple $I[n] Q[n-1] - I[n-1]Q[n]$ frequency error discriminator.

[image: Autocorrelation]

Comment: you wrote "Such a result can be averaged for very fine frequency offset correction"  dont understand it...could you give me more details?#

Comment: Doppler frequency is a fine correction, isnt?

Comment: could you provide some reason why you  would not recommend such an approach for Doppler correction?

Comment: @LeeLeeYa see ny second paragraph where I detail the reasons. Yes Doppler can both be fine and course frequency correction- during initial acquisition I would call that “course” and during subsequent tracking of much smaller changes I would call that “fine”.

Comment: Tracking loops will typically provide a function similar to averaging given their loop bandwidth- so while this shows an error discriminator that provides an error from sample to sample, it is the longer term average over many samples that would be of interest

Comment: 2. paragraph : what did you mean by "course tuning" ? As I understood, you wrote the main reason is peak of FFT which could  be variable for modulated signals. if i group samples, each group will have a different peak. I dont understand why it is a reason you wouldnt reccomend this approach?

Comment: The main reason is the amount of computations required to compute an FFT compared to the approach I gave which only requires a single complex multiplication. Course tuning is when the frequency is so far off that it would be out of range for the approach I gave (the phase from sample to sample will have rotated more than $2\pi$ such that the frequency is not resolvable- for this the FFT is useful for a course (rough order) correction. Once the course error is removed, FFT processing does not make sense in comparison to this for tracking given the relative processing involved.

Comment: Typically such algorithms are used in a tracking loop since frequency and phase is time varying, so is continuously tracked. This means we need to periodically compute and update the error and provide a correction to the loop.  The interest would then be on being able to do that with the minimum processing, and determining frequency and phase error with a single complex conjugate multiplier is a compelling comparison to other approaches.

Comment: For small angles when $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ can just use $I_1Q_2-I_2Q_1$ as the phase measurement. For larger angles $<2\pi$ can use $atan2(Q,I)$ as the phase measurement if accuracy is even required (In loops it is typically sufficient to continue to use $I_1Q_2-I_2Q_1$ for phase offsets $+/= \pi$ as the error signal during acquisition driving the loop to the small angle criteria in final tracking mode.) Outside of this range an FFT could be useful to determine the initial frequency offset such that the phase rotation from sample to sample stays within this criteria.

Comment: is it possible to skip FFT step and do corrections? in practice?

Comment: @LeeLeeYa Yes, there are other acquisition approaches. We're discouraged from having longer discussions in the comments as it flags the moderators. Did my response and previous comments sufficiently answer your primary question?

Comment: sue you did. Thank your Mr Boschen for taking your time

Comment: My pleasure. Best wishes with your implementation.

Comment: @LeeLeeYa If that's the case, please give Dan the check mark, and upvote his answer.